# Appending the HH:MI:SS to to_date function

Tags: sql, oracle, to-date, to-char

I have a table in DB from which I take values from a date field.I store this date value in a cursor. currently the date value is of the format DD:MON:YY. Now I convert this date into character using to_char function so as to append time 00:00:00 to it. now I tried converting back to the date format , but the timestamp is not appended and the date format is not as I have given( format is same as that of the date field in DB).but the to_char function returns the correct format as I have given.

Some of the code snippets are as follows:

Initialized a cursor as

```
cursor cur is
select to_char(STV_FROM_DATE,'DD:MON:YYYY:')STV_FROM_DATE :---from a table in DB
cur1 cur%rowtype;
begin
open cur;
loop
fetch cur into cur1;
dbms_output.put_line(cur_1.STV_FROM_DATE);
```

This is giving the value correctly as:

```
01:JAN:2000:
01:JAN:2000:
01:JAN:2000:
01:JAN:2000:
```

Now I appended the timestamp 00:00:00 to this and did the to_date operation as follows:

```
STV_FROM_DATE_BC := cur_1.STV_FROM_DATE;
STV_FROM_DATEBCKUP:=to_date(STV_FROM_DATE_BC,'DD:MM:YY:HH24:MI:SS');
dbms_output.put_line(STV_FROM_DATEBCKUP);
```

The result obtained is:

```
01-JAN-00
01-JAN-00
01-JAN-00
```

Could anyone help me to solve this issue and convert  the timestamp appended character to date?

Comment: you have to again use `to_char` function

Comment: Thanks Sathya for your quick response.

Comment: But the problem is that again I have to update this new appended value to the DB in a date field.

Comment: `Oracle` will display the format as per your **NLS_DATE_FORMAT**. Use `to_char` to display the format you want.

Answer (score 2):

**DBMS_OUTPUT** is to **DISPLAY**. so, to display a **DATE**, you need **TO_CHAR**.

> STV_FROM_DATEBCKUP:=to_date(STV_FROM_DATE_BC,'DD:MM:YY:HH24:MI:SS');
>   dbms_output.put_line(STV_FROM_DATEBCKUP);

Never use *YY*, always mention 4 digits **YYYY** for the complete year. You don't want to introduce the **Y2K** bug again. Above, you are trying to display the date value, but you did not mention the **format model** that you want to display. So simply use TO_CHAR along with proper format model.

**Reason** Without providing a proper format model, your client would just display according to your **locale-specific NLS settings**. For example, if I just display the sysdate, I would see the format that is mentioned in my **NLS_DATE_FORMAT** in **v$parameters**.

```
SQL> select parameter, value from v$nls_parameters where parameter='NLS_DATE_FORMAT';

PARAMETER            VALUE
-------------------- --------------------
NLS_DATE_FORMAT      DD-MON-RR

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
---------
27-JAN-15

SQL>
```

So, I got `27-JAN-15` as SYSDATE, since my NLS_DATE_FORMAT is `DD-MON-RR`. You could set it at system level or at session level.

```
SQL> alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD:MM:YYYY:HH24:MI:SS';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
27:01:2015:11:54:07

SQL>
```

So, you could either set your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` to set the format model that suits you. Let's see a test case -

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2    STV_FROM_DATE_BC   VARCHAR2(20);
  3    STV_FROM_DATEBCKUP DATE;
  4  BEGIN
  5    STV_FROM_DATEBCKUP:= NULL;
  6    STV_FROM_DATE_BC  :='01:JAN:2000:';
  7    STV_FROM_DATE_BC  :=STV_FROM_DATE_BC||'00:00:00';
  8    dbms_output.put_line('Input date literal = '||STV_FROM_DATE_BC);
  9    STV_FROM_DATEBCKUP:=to_date(STV_FROM_DATE_BC,'DD:MON:YYYY:HH24:MI:SS');
 10    dbms_output.put_line('Date without format model = '||STV_FROM_DATEBCKUP);
 11    dbms_output.put_line('Date with proper format model = '||TO_CHAR(STV_FROM_DATEBCKUP,'DD:MM:YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'));
 12  END;
 13  /
Input date literal = 01:JAN:2000:00:00:00
Date without format model = 01-JAN-00
Date with proper format model = 01:01:2000:00:00:00

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Please mark it answered if it has solved your issue.

Comment: Never say *never use YY*.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger, and an explanation would be good. I would say, to display, no issues with YY. To convert into date, NO.

Comment: But this appended date is not updated in the DB when I use the update command.

Comment: Is it not updated, or is it not being displayed? Post the details, don't say, show.

Comment: I executed the update command:                                                                                                      update SUBS_TARIFF_VARIATION_BACKUP set stv_from_date=STV_FROM_DATE_BCKUP,stv_to_date=STV_TO_DATE_BCKUP where STV_ID=stv_id_bckup ;                                                                                where the STV_ID is a unique ID.now the value getting posted in the DB is :                                                                                                             01-JAN-00 and not the appended date.

Comment: `select to_char(stv_from_date, 'DD:MM:YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from SUBS_TARIFF_VARIATION_BACKUP` What is the data type of `stv_from_date`?

Comment: stv_from_date and stv_to_date are date field.

Comment: Then it is just a display issue. follow the steps I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: There is no need whatsoever to do any manipulation to the data in the column. As others have said this is merely a display issue - the data is all there in the column, you just have to tell Oracle which bits of it you want to retrieve.